# Get a list of N items with K selections for each element?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

For example if I have a selection set K

```
K = ['a','b','c']
```

and a length N

```
N = 4
```

I want to return all possible:

```
['a','a','a','a']
['a','a','a','b']
['a','a','a','c']
['a','a','b','a']
...
['c','c','c','c']
```

I can do it with recursion but it is not interesting. Is there a more Pythonic way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That can be done with [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

```
>>> K = ['a','b','c']
>>> import itertools
>>> N = 4
>>> i = itertools.product(K,repeat = N)
>>> l = [a for a in i]
>>> l[:3]
[('a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'c')]
```

EDIT: I realized you actually want [`product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), not [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement).  Updated code.